# How to insert quotation marks in php file jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I searched other questions, but the codes that I saw in the samples looked different to mine, and I was unfamiliar with some of the vocabulary they were using.

As I am unfamiliar with coding and someone else wrote the code for me, I was wondering if someone could help.

Here is the section where I would like to add the quotation marks

```
var textarray = [
    "I wish I could like this song a million times",
    "Feel like hearing your little voice...",
    "Our goal is to remind everyone that we have to keep the smile...",
    "I care about you very much. I want you to be fine."
];
```

They are written in quotes, but on the website the quotation marks don't appear, so I know thats just for the code. But if I would like quotation marks to appear with the sentence on the website, what would I have to do? Would I have to add (") on each end of the sentences for example?

Comment: "I am trying to escape \"Escaping the quotes\"  " - escape quotes by using backward slash \"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape `"` with `\`:

```
var textarray = [
    "\"I wish I could like this song a million times\"",
];
```

Or use both `'` and `"`:

```
var textarray = [
    '"I wish I could like this song a million times"',
];
```

Comment: Remember that if there are more quotation marks, all of them must be escaped. `'"I'm causing an error"'`. `'"I\'m not"'`

Comment: Oh okay, I remember reading about escaping quotation marks, but I didn't really understand if it was the same thing I was looking for. Thanks for the clear instructions. Have a good day